# why css set same width for two div but show different widths

Tags: html, css, width

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
```

*this is the size of navigation which width is 50%*

```
#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 110px;
    width: 50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-25%;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 10000;
    height: 60px;
    opacity:0.7;
    padding:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:30px 0 0 0;
    margin:0;
}

#navigation ul li {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#3d3d3d;
    float:left;
    padding:0 20px 0 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

*this is the size of content which width is also 50%*

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top:180px;
    left:50%;
    height:800px;
    margin-left:-25%;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    padding:0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">BUtton 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BUtton 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BUtton 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BUtton 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I set navigation and content same width which are 50%, but when i open it in browser,     these two boxes are different width, anyone can help me?

Comment: Don't use padding, use margin instead. Also, you may want to encase all your main divs in a container which has a set width.

Comment: Or use `box-sizing:border-box` so that padding doesn't affect the overall width. (IE8 & up)

Comment: Just a note: `left: 50%; margin-left: -25%;` is the same as `left: 25%;`. Might as well keep things simple!

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you set the % in the `width` that element takes it in relation to his closest parent.

When you set the `position:fixed` for the `#navigation` this makes the `html` his parent while the `#content` take the `body` as his parent. The problem here is that for default de `html` tag has a `padding` value, now to make the body an html equals and the 50% widths equals set this in your css:

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

View the demo here **http://jsfiddle.net/cAtgd/3/**

Answer (score 0):

In your example change css part of **#content**:

```
position: relative;
```

to:

```
position:absolute;
```

This is because in case of **relative** the div was appearing relative to where it should appear in the document. That means in your case relative to the properties in *'#navigation'*

While in case of **absolute** div appears where you exactly tell it to. Irrespective of other elements positioned before or after.